# File/image upload via CCK and Nginx + FastCGI

Tags: entities, files

I am using the ImageField module with Pressflow, Nginx, and FastCGI. When I go to add a file via the standard ImageField CCK upload widget on a node, the Upload "throbber" does its thing, Drupal does not report any problem. The upload completes fine, but no thumbnail is generated in `imagefield_thumbnails`, and no ImageCache presets are generated.

I can see the file in the right place on the server. It feels for all the world like a file permissions problem, but I'm getting no such warnings from Drupal or PHP and the file is `chmod 664` and belongs to `www-data` (which is the user Nginx is running as). So I can see no reason why PHP would not be able to read the image.

Furthermore, all the ImageField and ImageCache target directories are `chmod 777` and owned by `www-data`, so again, no reason why the application would not be able to write there. *And* anyway, no errors suggest that is the problem, in either `/var/log/messages` or in `/var/log/nginx/error.log`. It makes no sense!

Can anyone shed some light? Is there any simple step I need to follow (or a missing package I need) to make Drupal work, or am I doing something stupid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, turns out unbeknownst to me someone had added rules in the `.htaccess` file pointing image loading to another server, which, of course, did not have the created presets and thumbnails. Gah!

Another gotcha in this was the `$base_url` variable was set in `settings.php` to force Drupal to load a from a specific site, regardless of the one requested.

Hopefully this will help someone in the future.